# How to decrypt pbkdf2 encrypted text without knowing the IV

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to decrypt an encrypted text.
I have the salt value, iteration count and key length. But i don't have the initialization vector (IV) value, how can i go about and decrypt this. I also have secret key.

For time being I am using some random IV value whose size is 16 bytes.
But still i am not able to decrypt the value properly.
Can anyone please help as i am stuck with this for a long time?

---

Below are the values which were given to me.

```
salt= EW0h0yUcDX72WU9UiKiCwDpXsJg=, Iteration=128,Keylenght=16.
MasterKeyName="Passphrase1", MACMethod algo = hmac-sha1,    MACKey="jq/NdikC7AZf0Z+HEL5NrCICV8XW+ttzl/8687hVGHceoyJAaFws+111plQH 6Mlg" encrypted kae =   "pM7VB/KomPjq2cKaxPr5cKT1tUZN5tGMI+u1XKJTG1la+ThraPpLKlL2plKk6vQE"   and valuemac="lbu+9OcLArnj6mS7KYOKDa4zRU0=".
Secret key = "xxxxxxxxxxx".
```

---

Below is the code which I am using to decrypt.

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretkey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount, keyStrength);    
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
AlgorithmParameters params = dcipher.getParameters();
iv = "0000000000000000".getBytes();
System.out.println("IV " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(iv));
dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));      
byte[] decryptedData = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(base64EncryptedData);
byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(decryptedData);
```

Comment: PBKDFv2 is a **hash**.  It is (hopefully) mathematically impossible to decrypt.

Comment: When you decrypt, do you get 16 bytes of rubbish followed by the correctly decrypted message?  If so, then the first sixteen bytes of the cyphertext are the IV.

Comment: Please not that being able to decrypt without an exception does not mean you have found the key; any ciphertext with the correct block size decrypts for a block cipher that does not use an authenticated encryption mode. It just decrypts to garbage.

Comment: First of all, a zero IV does not contain `0` characters, it contains bytes set to zero. In Java you get this by simply creating an array with the correct size (as Java initializes the bytes with zero values). To get the next 16 bytes, you could generate an AES key with the same size using the `factory`. To check if the IV has been pre-prended you need to split the ciphertext array in two, I'll leave you with that as an assignment. If your plaintext is more than 1 block and you don't see the expected information at the start of the second block, then not only the IV is incorrect.

Comment: Did you succeed with the comment above? Please don't abandon the question. Unfortunately, I don't think I have other ideas regarding decryption without knowing the IV (and there are unlikely to be more, knowing CBC mode)...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot decrypt the *first* block of CBC encrypted ciphertext if you don't know the IV.

It is however not unlikely that you *can* retrieve the IV value:

- often the IV value is 16 bytes retrieved after the key bytes) generated from the PBKDF;
- the IV is often prepended to the ciphertext, resulting in one block of garbage before the full plaintext during decryption;
- not secure but the IV is also left out or set to a constant value, with an all-zero IV being the most common (this is identical in CBC mode to not using any IV.)

Comment: I have edited my question, i have given the details about the values which i am using to decrypt. I tried your suggestions but didn't get the proper value.
 As i am new to this encryption field can you suggest what i am doing is right?
It would be great if you can point me to website where i can learn about encryption using pskc in details

Comment: Unfortunately I'm self-thought, so I often don't know where my information originated from. I'll respond on your question as well.